# No implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)?

Tags: ruby, redhat

I'm trying to write a script that will get a system ID from Red Hat Satellite/Spacewalk, which uses XMLRPC.  I'm trying to get the ID which is the first value when using the XMLRPC client using the system name.

I'm referencing [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Satellite/5.6/html/API_Overview/sect-system-getId.html) from Red Hat for the method used below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "xmlrpc/client"


@SATELLITE_URL = "satellite.rdu.salab.redhat.com"
@SATELLITE_API = "/rpc/api"
@SATELLITE_LOGIN = "********"
@SATELLITE_PASSWORD = "*******"

@client = XMLRPC::Client.new(@SATELLITE_URL, @SATELLITE_API)

@key = @client.call("auth.login", @SATELLITE_LOGIN, @SATELLITE_PASSWORD)

@getsystemid = @client.call("system.getId", @key, 'cfme038')

print "#{@getsystemid}"

@systemid = @getsystemid ['id']
```

The output of getsystemid looks like this:

```
[{"id"=>1000010466, "name"=>"cfme038", "last_checkin"=>#<XMLRPC::DateTime:0x007f9581042428 @year=2013, @month=12, @day=26, @hour=14, @min=31, @sec=28>}]
```

But when I try to just get just `id` I get this error:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Write as

```
@systemid = @getsystemid[0]['id']
```

Your `@getsystemid` is not a `Hash`, it is an `Array` of `Hash`. `@getsystemid[0]` will give you the intended hash `{"id"=>1000010466, "name"=>"cfme038", "last_checkin"=>#}`. Now you can use [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) method to access the value of the hash by using its keys.