# Why am I getting "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" when trying to get Nested JSON attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

My Rails app is reading in JSON from a Bing API, and creating a record for each result. However, when I try to save one of the nested JSON attributes, I'm getting `Resource creation error: no implicit conversion of String into Integer`.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Demo": {
    "_type": "News",
    "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/news/search?q=european+football",
    "totalEstimatedMatches": 2750000,
    "value": [
      {
        "provider": [
          {
            "_type": "Organization",
            "name": "Tuko on MSN.com"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Hope for football fans as top European club resume training despite coronavirus threat",
        "url": "https://www.msn.com/en-xl/news/other/hope-for-football-fans-as-top-european-club-resume-training-despite-coronavirus-threat/ar-BB12eC6Q",
        "description": "Bayern have returned to training days after leaving camp following the outbreak of coronavirus. The Bundesliga is among top European competitions suspended."
        }
      }
```

The attribute I'm having trouble with is [:provider][:name].

Here's my code:

```
  def handle_bing
    @terms = get_terms

    @terms.each do |t|
      news = get_news(t)

      news['value'].each do |n|
        create_resource(n)
      end
    end
  end  

  def get_terms
    term = ["European football"]
  end

  def get_news(term)
    accessKey = "foobar"
    uri  = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
    path = "/bing/v7.0/news/search"

    uri = URI(uri + path + "?q=" + URI.escape(term))
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    request['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = accessKey

    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end

    response.each_header do |key, value|
       # header names are coerced to lowercase
       if key.start_with?("bingapis-") or key.start_with?("x-msedge-") then
          puts key + ": " + value
       end
    end

    return JSON(response.body)
  end


  def create_resource(news)
    Resource.create(
      name: news['name'],
      url: news['url'],
      description: news['description'],
      publisher: news['provider']['name']
    )
  end
```

I looked at these questions, but they didn't help me:

[Extract specific field from JSON nested hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036657/extract-specific-field-from-json-nested-hashes)

[No implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790499/no-implicit-conversion-of-string-into-integer-typeerror)

[Why do I get "no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549098/why-do-i-get-no-implicit-conversion-of-string-into-integer-typeerror)

UPDATE:
I also tried updating the code to:

`publisher: news['provider'][0]['name']`, but I received the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because "*provider*" is an array.

it should be accessed with index.

```
[:value][0][:provider][0][:name]
```

same goes with "*value*".

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I did try that based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790499/no-implicit-conversion-of-string-into-integer-typeerror.  I made it  'publisher: news['provider'][0]['name'],' but I get the same error.  I'll add that to the question.

Comment: what is the output when you post [:provider]?

Comment: If I do `puts news['provider'}`, I get {"_type"=>"Organization", "name"=>"UPI.com", "image"=>{"thumbnail"=>{"contentUrl"=>"https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_d88c5b6fb27b317026ee10242444fb8b&pid=news"}}}

Comment: When I change `publisher: news['provider'][0]['name']` to either`publisher: news[0]['provider'][0]['name']` or `publisher: [:value][0]['provider'][0]['name']`, I get Resource creation error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: you need to use symbol to all keys [:value][0][:provider][0][:name]

Comment: Hmmm.  Even when I do `publisher: [:value][0][:provider][0][:name]`, I get the same error.

Comment: what is the output if you try this: publisher: news[:provider]

Comment: I get {"_type"=>"Organization", "name"=>"UPI.com", "image"=>{"thumbnail"=>{"contentUrl"=>"bing.com/th?id=AR_d88c5b6fb27b317026ee10242444fb8b&pid=news"}}}

Comment: and this one... publisher: [:provider][0]

Comment: puts [:provider][0] => `provider`

Comment: [:provider][0][:name] should work then... maybe you need to check if it has data: provider: [:provider][0].present? ? [:provider][0][:name] : ""